# Execute tableau commands Through java

Tags: java, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to execute 3-7 commands using Java. First, I need to change the directory with `cd` and later execute commands 2) and 3).

1)

```
Process p = runtime.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /C \"cd C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau Server\\8.2\\bin");
```

and then i want to write

2)

```
runtime.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \tabcmd login -s http://localhost:80 -u c200433 -p venkat@#");
```

and in the below command i am getting file name from a string, can I use this format ?

3)

```
runtime.exec("tabcmd publish C:\\Users\\c200433\\Desktop\\Ana\\".getBytes()+filename+" --db-username IIP_RBM_USER --db-password Ytpqxsb9dw".getBytes()));
```

I need to execute all these commands. How do i do this?

Comment: What doesn't work and what error do you get?

Comment: After executing
Process p = runtime.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /C \"cd C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau Server\\8.2\\bin"
it retuns to main command prompt and executes 
tabcmd login -s http://localhost:80 -u c200433 -p venkat@#"
says tabcmd not found (Since it is excuting in main cmd)

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Java. If the commands are executed, but do not do what you want them to do, it is a command-line interpreter issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are missing something important about how `cmd` works.  Specifically, each `cmd` instance has its own "current directory".  So  ...

- When you run `cd` in  a `cmd` it only affects that instance.
- When you run `runtime.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe ...` twice, you get two separate `cmd` instances, one after the other.

So what (I think) you are attempting to do here simply won't work.

Instead you should:

- generate a `BAT` file that contains the entire sequence of commands, OR
- put a `cd` into every `cmd` line that you execute, OR
- use absolute pathnames so that you don't *need* to `cd`.